# text-decoration in css doesn't work as it should

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using this code to implement text differencing in javascript. The code works fine.

Then I tried to add text-decoration in order to have a line over the incorrect parts of the sentence, something like this:
[image]

The problem is  `text-decoration: line-through;` in CSS doesn't work as it should here.

Here is CSS where I tried to add text-decoration:

Note: I can change text and background colors here but text-decoration does not work!

**del**: Incorrect and red parts

**ins** : Correct and green parts

```
del {

    text-decoration: line-through !important; 
    color: #b30000;
    background: #fadad7;
}
ins {
    background: #eaf2c2;
    color: #406619;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Js is a library please feel free to ask it if you want to have look at it. But here is the only parts containing **ins** and **del** :

```
  convertChangesToXML: function (changes) {
            var ret = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
                var change = changes[i];
                if (change.added) {
                    ret.push("<ins class='diff'>");
                } else if (change.removed) {
                    ret.push("<del class='diff'>");
                }

                ret.push(escapeHTML(change.value));

                if (change.added) {
                    ret.push('</ins>');
                } else if (change.removed) {
                    ret.push('</del>');
                }
            }
            return ret.join('');
        },
```

Comment: can you give an example you are passing to `convertChangesToXML` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be some strange issue here, it just works fine for me:

```css
hi{
text-decoration: line-through !important;
}
```

```html
<hi class="hi">Hallo</hi>
```

if this does not work for you (somehow?), you could still return a string containing the inline style like this: (This should always work).

`ret.push("<ins class='diff' style='text-decoration: line-through;'>");`

Comment: This is working : ``ret.push("<del class='diff' style='text-decoration: line-through;'>");``

Comment: Glad I could help you! The only thing  can think of is this: The more specificly you apply your CSS to an element, the more you can be sure, that it is not overwritten. So maybe your class `diff` has something overriding the style of `del`, e.g. `diff` has `text-decoration:something !important;` also. The inline is always the MOST specific thing that can be applied, so the inline css can't really be overwritten